# Openfire Client for Windows Mobile

Tags: xmpp, openfire, windows-mobile

Where can I find an Openfire client that works on Windows Mobile?

Comment: OpenFire uses the XMPP protocol, look for a client that supports XMPP. Might be a better search keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Beejive is quite awesome, and in open beta for Windows Mobile.

http://www.beejive.com/winmo/

Answer (score 0):

[IM+](http://www.shapeservices.com/en/products/details.php?product=im&platform=none) does jabber also.  Though personally I +1'ed ChrisSoyars Beejive recommendation as that is what I use on my BlackBerry :)